# Some questions about CkZip

Tags: chilkat

I'm evaluating Chilkat and working with CkZip component to see if it feets our requirements. I have some questions derived of my tests:

1. When I put an event callback object, in: void FileZipped(const char
   *path, _int64 fileSize, _int64 compressedSize, bool *abort);

   I always get the same value for fileSize and compressedSize
   (compression level was put to 9 and algo to deflate) Is it
   intentionally / normal? Maybe it's a bug...
2. It seems that ProgressInfo event is received for the whole zip, so
   when compressing a single large file and it tooks a bit of time, we
   have no feedback about compression progress (ToBeZipped and
   FileZipped received, with a difference of minutes).
3. I see the method AppendCompressed. So compressing a file with
   CkCompression I can obtain compressed data and apply to
   AppendCompressed directly. But documentation says CkCompression
   handles "ppmd", "deflate", "zlib", "bzip2", or "lzw", and
   AppendCompressed says that data should be unencrypted deflate data.
   When we are building zipx files with lzma algo, AppendCompressed
   data will took deflate compressed data and recompress with lzma? or
   AppendCompressed data only takes deflate data so we cannot make a
   lzma zipx file using AppendCompressed?.

Thanks in advance!

PD: Sorry, had to post here because chilkat forum says "This forum is closed. Post instead to stackoverflow.com with tag "chilkat""

Answer (score 0):

Due lack of support/answer from Chilkat we have chosen to use another library that for now conforms to what we want/expect and does not have the mentioned failures.

Thanks!